# Python list comprehension with same function in guard and result

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I was wondering if someone has a nice clean Pythonic and effective technique for implementing comprehensions that involve the same expression in the guard as in the result. 
To be clear, consider the following simple example:

```
def f(a):
    print "Calling", a
    return a + 1

print [ f(v) for v in xrange(3) if f(v) > 1 ]
```

This will print

```
Calling 0
Calling 1
Calling 1
Calling 2
Calling 2
[2, 3]
```

proving that f is called twice for most elements. This is fine and what we want if f has side-effects, but if f is some expensive operation without side-effects, the duplicate call is not desirable. But the solution that only calls f once for each element seems clumsy/verbose to me:

```
intermediate = ( f(v) for v in xrange(3) ) 
print [ r for r in intermediate if r > 1 ]
```

even if it is contracted into one line

```
print [ r for r in ( f(v) for v in xrange(3) ) if r > 1 ]
```

So, can anyone come up with something better?

Comment: I think your last two code blocks are as good as it gets.

Comment: opt1. double comprehension (as in nested); opt2. comprehension + filter; opt3. memoize `f()`

Comment: I think the approach with an intermediate generator is the best thing python can offer. It would be great to have a `let` inside of the comprehension, but this is not haskell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **`filter()`** function:

```
filter(lambda x: x > 1, [ f(v) for v in xrange(3)])
```

But that's about as verbose as your last suggested solution.

Comment: No need for an intermediate list, generator should work too

Comment: This is not cleaner than the OP's suggestion, and probably slower because of the lambda calls. I would go for simplicity and stick to one generator + one list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

How about memoizing `f`, e.g.:?

```
def f(...): ...

def some_or_other():
    f = functools.lru_cache(1)(f)
    [ f(v) for v in xrange(3) if f(v) > 1 ]
```

Memoizing locally, withing the scope of your call site has the advantage that once `some_or_other()` returns, "memo" memory will be garbage collected, and you don't have to worry about references to `v` that were passed to `f()`.

Since it's local, memo size limit 1 is sufficient.

In the simple case, you can also memoize `f` globally:

```
@functools.lru_cache()
def f(...): ...

[ f(v) for v in xrange(3) if f(v) > 1 ]
```

Comment: P.S. `lru_cache()`: New in [Python] version 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

What Andrés Pérez-Albela H. said, except use [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) built-in function:

```
filter(lambda x: x > 1, map(f, xrange(3)))
```

You could also look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module, but I'm not sure if it can be applied to this example. In more complex situations though it may offer a solution.